# CSS to reveal content if radio button checked not displaying correctly on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form which is using CSS to "reveal" some additional options if a radio button is selected.

This works fine but on mobile, the additional options cover the submit button and the text is hard to read.

the HTML form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>MooWoos Stall Booking</title>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,800">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!--build:css css/styles.min.css-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <!--endbuild-->

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light">
        <a class="logo"><img src="assets/logo_opt.png"></a>
    </nav>

    <hr>

    <div class="modal fade" id="redirect_page" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="form-horizontal">

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <div id="user_msg" align="left">Booking successful! Redirecting to PayPal... </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 bookingform">
            <h1>Stall Booking Form</h1>
            <p class="lead">
                Fill out the form to book and pay for your stall!
            </p>
            <form id="bookingForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name </label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" value="" title="Please enter your name" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="address">Address </label>
                    <textarea name="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Address" value="" title="Please enter your address" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="phone">Telephone Number </label>
                    <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Telephone Number" value="" title="Please enter the best telephone number to contact you on" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email </label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" value="" title="Please enter your Email address" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="date">Which date would you like to book? </label>
                    <p><input type="radio" name="date" value="13th September" required/> Sunday 13th September</p>
                    <p><input type="radio" name="date" value="6th February" /> Saturday 6th February</p>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>What type of stall do you require?</label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="stallType" id="stallType-Preloved" value="Preloved" required>
                        <label for="stallType-Preloved">Preloved</label>
                        <div class="reveal-if-active">
                            <label for="c-rail">Will you be bringing a clothes rail? </label>
                            <input type="radio" id=c-rail-yes name="c-rail" value="Yes" /> Yes
                            <input type="radio" id=c-rail-no name="c-rail" value="No" /> No
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="stallType" id="stallType-Craft" value="Craft">
                        <label for="stallType-Craft">Craft</label>
                        <div class="reveal-if-active">
                            <label for="craftName">What name do you use?</label>
                            <input type="text" id="craftName" name="craftName" class="require-if-active" placeholder="Craft Name" title="Please provide us with your Craft name" value="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="stallType" id="stallType-Business" value="Business">
                        <label for="stallType-Business">Business</label>
                        <div class="reveal-if-active">
                            <label for="bizName">What is your business name?</label>
                            <input type="text" id="bizName" name="bizName" class="require-if-active" placeholder="Business Name" title="Please provide us with your Business name" value="" />
                            <label for="insurance">Do you have Public Liability Insurance?</label>
                            <input type="radio" id="insurance-yes" name="insurance" class="require-if-active" data-require-pair="#stallType-Business" title="We will require proof of this prior to market day" value="Yes"/> Yes
                            <input type="radio" id="insurance-no" name="insurance" class="require-if-active" data-require-pair="#stallType-Business" title="Our insurance does not cover other businesses. Please ensure you have adequate cover and provide us with proof prior to market day" value="No"/> No
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" id="submit-form" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="Book & Pay" />
            </form>
            <p></p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <hr>

    <footer>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <p>Copyright &copy; MooWoos 2018. Booking Form by Luke Brewerton</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </footer>

</div>

<!--build:js js/mwbookings-min.js -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.serialize-object.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

</body>
</html>
```

The radio buttons `stallType` group are the ones, using the CSS class `reveal-if-active` on the labels and `require-if-active` on the form inputs.

CSS:

```
.reveal-if-active {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  transition: 0.5s;
  input[type="radio"]:checked ~ &,
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ & {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

My JS file:

```
var $form = $('form#bookingForm'),
    url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwaEsXX1iK8nNkkvL57WCYHJCtMAbXlfSpSn3rsJj2spRi-41Y/exec'

function disableAll() {
    $('#c-rail-yes').attr('required', false).attr('disabled', true);
    $('#c-rail-no').attr('required', false).attr('disabled', true);
    $('#craftName').attr('required', false).attr('disabled', true);
    $('#bizName').attr('required', false).attr('disabled', true);
    $('#insurance-yes').attr('required', false).attr('disabled', true);
    $('#insurance-no').attr('required', false).attr('disabled', true);
}

$('#stallType-Preloved').change(function () {
    if(this.checked) {
        disableAll();
        $('#c-rail-yes').attr('required', true).attr('disabled', false);
        $('#c-rail-no').attr('required', true).attr('disabled', false);
    }
});

$('#stallType-Craft').change(function () {
    if(this.checked) {
        disableAll();
        $('#craftName').attr('required', true).attr('disabled', false);
    }
});

$('#stallType-Business').change(function () {
    if(this.checked) {
        disableAll();
        $('#bizName').attr('required', true).attr('disabled', false);
        $('#insurance-yes').attr('required', true).attr('disabled', false);
        $('#insurance-no').attr('required', true).attr('disabled', false);
    }
});

$('#submit-form').on('click', function(e) {
    var valid = this.form.checkValidity();
    if (valid) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: $form.serializeObject(),
            success: function () {
                $('#redirect_page').modal('show');
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    location.reload()
                }, 3000);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Would this be better done via jQuery? If so, how?

Comment: please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example. There's nothing wrong on that little bit of code you provide, so the issue is most likely in the way you position the submit button... which you are not showing at all.

Comment: The submit button is shown in the HTML above. The line is <input type="submit" id="submit-form" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="Book & Pay" />

Comment: but how are you positioning it?

Comment: It is just in the <form> tag, not in it's own <div> is this the error?

Comment: ok... if you're not positioning the submit at all, then the issue is your max-height and overflow visible. Why are you using those?

Comment: I followed a tutorial, months ago, it's only now i've taken up this project again. What would the correct settings be?

Comment: just delete those 2 properties and see what happens...

Comment: This just then hides the text behind the label below

Comment: show your code man...

Comment: I removed the Overflow and max-height properties

Comment: I understood. But show your complete code, or better yet, provide a  minimal, complete and verifiable example. Can't keep guessing

Comment: I added my JS file to the above, which will produce an MCV example :)

Answer (score 0):

The jquery function required is as follows

**HTML**

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <label>What type of stall do you require?</label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="stallType" id="stallType-Preloved" value="Preloved" required>
                        <label for="stallType-Preloved">Preloved</label>
                        <div class="reveal-if-active">
                            <label for="c-rail">Will you be bringing a clothes rail? </label>
                            <input type="radio" id=c-rail-yes name="c-rail" value="Yes" /> Yes
                            <input type="radio" id=c-rail-no name="c-rail" value="No" /> No
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="stallType" id="stallType-Craft" value="Craft">
                        <label for="stallType-Craft">Craft</label>
                        <div class="reveal-if-active">
                            <label for="craftName">What name do you use?</label>
                            <input type="text" id="craftName" name="craftName" class="require-if-active" placeholder="Craft Name" title="Please provide us with your Craft name" value="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" name="stallType" id="stallType-Business" value="Business">
                        <label for="stallType-Business">Business</label>
                        <div class="reveal-if-active">
                            <label for="bizName">What is your business name?</label>
                            <input type="text" id="bizName" name="bizName" class="require-if-active" placeholder="Business Name" title="Please provide us with your Business name" value="" />
                            <label for="insurance">Do you have Public Liability Insurance?</label>
                            <input type="radio" id="insurance-yes" name="insurance" class="require-if-active" data-require-pair="#stallType-Business" title="We will require proof of this prior to market day" value="Yes"/> Yes
                            <input type="radio" id="insurance-no" name="insurance" class="require-if-active" data-require-pair="#stallType-Business" title="Our insurance does not cover other businesses. Please ensure you have adequate cover and provide us with proof prior to market day" value="No"/> No
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document ).ready(function() {
  $("input:radio[name='stallType']").change(function (e) {
        $(".reveal-if-active").hide();
        $(e.currentTarget).parent().find(".reveal-if-active").show();
        });
});
```

Codepen link for reference

https://codepen.io/YasirKamdar/pen/vpMayq

Comment: This is wrapping round the `c-rail` radio buttons. It should be the `stallType` ones, with each one (`stallType-Preloved` etc) having it's own additional fields that show.

Comment: $(document ).ready(function() {
  $("input:radio[name='stallType']").change(function (e) {
        $(".reveal-if-active").hide();
        $(e.currentTarget).parent().find(".reveal-if-active").show();
        });
});

Answer (score 0):

Replace those nonsensical max-height declarations for height:0 and height:auto.

```
.reveal-if-active {
  opacity: 0;
  height:0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  transition: 0.5s;
  input[type="radio"]:checked ~ &,
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ & {
    opacity: 1;
    height:auto;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```